# android send file to jsp with loopj

Tags: android, jsp, loopj

I have managed to send files to jsp from html. 
html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
Select a file to upload: <br />
<form action = "UploadServel.jsp" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type = "file" name = "file" size = "50" />
<br />
Email <input name="email" id="email" />
 <br />
 <input type = "submit" value = "Upload File" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

My jsp code is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import = "java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "javax.servlet.http.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import = "java.nio.file.Files" %>
 <%@ page import = "java.nio.file.Paths" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"                   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
File file ;
int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
//String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");
//make dir from user_id so test will be user_id
String fileName = "";
String fieldvalue = "";
String filePath = "C://upload";
String filePath1 = "";
Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C://upload//" ));

String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rack";
String dbuser = "root";
String dbpassword = "";

Connection theConnection = null;
PreparedStatement theStatement = null;

System.out.println(filePath);
// Verify the content type
String contentType = request.getContentType();
System.out.println(contentType);

if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {
  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
System.out.println("step 2");
  factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));
  // Create a new file upload handler
System.out.println("step 3");
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
System.out.println("step 4");
  upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
  try { 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
     // Process the uploaded file items
System.out.println("step 5");
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();
     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     System.out.println("JSP File upload");

     while ( i.hasNext () ) {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
System.out.println("step 6");
        if (fi.isFormField()){
            String fieldname = fi.getFieldName();
            System.out.println(fieldname);
            fieldvalue = fi.getString();
            System.out.println(fieldvalue);
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("C://upload//" + fieldvalue));
            filePath1 = "C://upload//" + fieldvalue;
            System.out.println("C://upload//" + fieldvalue);
        }
        if ( !fi.isFormField () ) {
            // Get the uploaded file parameters
            String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
            System.out.println(fieldName);
            fileName = fi.getName();
            System.out.println(fieldName);
            boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
            long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();

            // Write the file
            if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ) { 
               file = new File( filePath + "//" + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
               System.out.println("1 " + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")));
            } else {
               file = new File( filePath +  "//" + fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
               System.out.println("2 " + fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1));
            }
            fi.write(file) ;

            out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath +"//" + fileName);
            //insert to db fileName

         }



      }
     Files.move(Paths.get(filePath +"//" + fileName), Paths.get(filePath1 +"//" + fileName));
     String photoPath = filePath1 +"//" + fileName;
     System.out.println("Copy From: " + filePath +"//" + fileName + " to " + filePath1 +"//" + fileName);

     String str1 = "SELECT * FROM users ";
     String str2 = "UPDATE building SET building_photo = '"+photoPath+"' where building_id='"+fieldvalue+"' ";


     try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
      theConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,dbuser,dbpassword);  
         theStatement = theConnection.prepareStatement(str1);
         ResultSet theResult = theStatement.executeQuery();
         if(theResult.next()){
            //System.out.println("ok");
            int count = theStatement.executeUpdate(str2);

         }else{

         }

     }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Exception occured! "+e.getMessage()+" "+e.getStackTrace());
     }  finally {

         try { theStatement.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
         try { theConnection.close(); } catch (Exception e) { /* ignored */ }
     }
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
  } catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
} else {
  out.println("<html>");
  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
  out.println("</body>");
  out.println("</html>");
 }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is with android code, i use loopj but jsp compile give me this

```
C://upload
multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------1496672086042
step 2
step 2
step 3
step 4
step 5
JSP File upload
```

and finally android code is

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import com.loopj.android.http.RequestParams;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView iv_result;
String name;
String dir;
String path;
String path2;
TextView tv_file;
EditText et_name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv_result = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_result);
    Button btn_camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_camera);
    Button btn_gallery = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_gallery);
    et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_name);
    tv_file = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file);
    dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
    File newdir = new File(dir);
    newdir.mkdirs();
    name = et_name.getText().toString();

    btn_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            name = et_name.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });

    btn_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(pickPhoto , 1);
        }
    });

    Button send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_path);

    send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String filePath = tv_file.getText().toString();

            File pick = new File(filePath);
            if (pick!= null) {
                Log.d("path", "file created");

                String url = "http://uploadFile_Android.jsp";
                String boundary = "-------------" + System.currentTimeMillis();

                RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
                params.put("building_id", 1);
                params.put("path", path2);
                try {
                    params.put("picture", pick);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                }

                AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                client.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary="+boundary);
                client.post(url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.d("path", "success");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                        error.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
                });

            } else{
                Log.d("path", "file don't exist");
            }
            }
    });
 }

private File getFile() {
    File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
    File image = new File(folder, name + ".jpg");
    return image;
}

 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case 0:
            path = "sdcard/camera_app/" + name + ".jpg";
            iv_result.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
            tv_file.setText(path);
            String filePath = path;
            Log.d("path", "filePath:"+filePath);
            break;
        case 1:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String path1 = selectedImage.getPath();
                path2 = path1 + ".jpg";
                Log.d("path", path2);
                iv_result.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                tv_file.setText(path2);
                filePath = path2;
                Log.d("path", "filePath:"+filePath);
            }
            break;
     }

   }
}
```

activity xml is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.atdevelopment.takephoto.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_camera"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="camera" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_galery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="galery" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.43" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/et_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_file"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.07"
    android:text="TextView" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_path"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you were able to solve the problem, it is perfectly ok to answer your own question..